# How to add Post Tags to a new <meta> element in header.php?

Tags: php, tags, headers

How to add Post Tags inside a new  element in header.php?

I'm probably overlooking an obvious function in the WordPress Codex.

I have tried adding these to header.php:

```
<meta name="page-tags" content="<?php the_tags(); ?>">
```

=> produces some unwanted html (I do not want to change core in the wp-includes folder

and

```
<meta name="post-tags-here" content="<?php get_the_tag_list(); ?>" >
```

=> doesn't print

and

```
<meta name="post-tags-here" content="<?php tag_description(); ?>" >
```

=> doesn't print

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_the_tags()` instead of `the_tags()`, [`get_the_tags()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) does the following for you:

> Returns an array of objects, one object for each tag assigned to the post.

with which you can work with to achieve what you want. See the [examples](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags#Examples) on the codex page for more information.

Comment: thank you!

This one works:
<meta name="print-post-tag" content="<?php
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags) {
        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
            echo $tag->name;
        }
    }
    ?>
" >

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt is close, but you need to echo the result of the function and you may want to provide it with some arguments. The below should output the list of tags space-separated:

```
<meta name="post-tags-here" content="<?php echo get_the_tag_list( '', ' ', '' ); ?>" >
```

Comment: Are sure this will get rid of the link, so the `a` tag? Because I don't think so, I'm relatively sure actually.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still ouputs the entire Anchor element tag as constructed in category-template.php.

Comment: ah, correct. you'll need to go with @ialocin's answer